# WordPress menu strange issue

Tags: wordpress

While customizing the wordpress menu I am having serious issues.

```
$setup = array( 'menu' => '', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => 'menu', 'container_id' => 'menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => 'menu',
    'echo' => true, 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth' => 0, 'walker' => '', 'theme_location' => '','theme_location' => 'primary' );

wp_nav_menu($setup);
```

The issue:
You can see in the code that I have setted the `menu_id` as "menu". OR `'menu_id' => 'menu'`

But it is not applying, only the menu_class is applying the id is not for the menu container. But why???? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to apply css styles check if there is !important keyword in front of any style property.